# GraphicsMagick unrecognized virtual pixel method (Transparent)

Tags: node.js, image-processing, imagemagick, graphicsmagick, node-imagemagick

I'm using GraphicsMagick to modify the image. It is working fine on windows but when i try running it on ubuntu it gives me an error

**Unrecognized virtual pixel method (transparent).**

Below is the command i'm using

```
gm convert newImages/December31201542014pm3630/profileLarge.jpg -background transparent -rotate -2 -matte -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective \"0,0 0,0   213,0 213,20   213,160 213,165   0,80 0,80 \" newImages/December31201542014pm3630/skew_profile.png
```

Comment: Don't know what the reason is, but you could maybe try `-virtual-pixel none` as a synonym, or, since your background is transparent, you could maybe try `-virtual-pixel background`. Also, try adding `-matte` immediately after loading your initial image to create an alpha layer since a JPEG will not naturally have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I simply installed Imagemagick.